# Disable Accessibility in login screen

Tags: gdm, accessibility

There's a funny joke going through my class:
Wait for a colleague to leave his laptop and restart the laptop / change user. Then, at login screen (GDM), enable all possible accessibility features and enjoy an unusable laptop...

Is it possible to hide the little accessibility icon at the lower right edge? I've once tried to change the theme somehow, but didn't succeed.

Thank you
Tom

PS: Yep, I was the first to do that funny joke. :)

Comment: This is the new way for doing it! https://askubuntu.com/q/1029476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once found a solution for this and it probably still works.

```
sudo -H gedit /var/lib/gdm/.gconf.mandatory/%gconf-tree.xml
```

Locate this part:

```
<dir name="accessibility">
<dir name="keyboard">
<entry name="enable" ... type="bool" value="true"/>
</dir>
</dir>
```

and set `enable` to `false`.

**Edit:** I changed it after I posted this and can confirm it still works. Icon for accessibility is gone from the login screen.