# How can I remove Accessibility icon GDM3 (Login Screen)

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gdm

I want to remove Accessibility" icon on GDM3 login screen.
Google cannot help me with this.

How I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions suggested in this question askubuntu.com/questions/38896/ this question askubuntu.com/questions/554026 or this question askubuntu.com/questions/53032

Comment: @LinuxSailorTech yes but not solved. This solutions is for "gdm". Not "gdm3". And "gdm3" is newer version of "gdm". (Gnome Display Manager)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu/ GDM are you using?

Comment: @LinuxSailorTech , Ubuntu 18.04 (customized from me), gdm3 (installed by Vanilla Gnome)

Comment: I have just had a look through nearly all the settings that would appear to be relevant using dconf and disabled all those to do with accessibility unfortunately, I was also unable to make the Icon disappear I will do a bit more research, but I fear that I will be unable to help you. Just out of curiosity why do you wish to remove the accessibility icon in the first place?

Comment: Reason is if I enable "High Contrast" theme is broking my Operation System (customized Ubuntu distro.) default GTK3 theme and some Gnome Extensions.

Comment: Just been looking at the source code for GDM found here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 and as far as I can tell the setting that should control weather accessibility settings are available should be `org/gnome/desktop/a11y always-show-universal-access-status`. But if disabling this is not working then it may be worth taking it up with the dev team on Launchpad or the GNOME project, as this is currently well beyond the scope of my skills to be able to solve. So sorry that I was unable to help, but I hope you can sort your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Background:***

It worked before with 18.04.X version [Change cursor color after log out on ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/1123546/739431)
It did not work recently [Night Light on GDM screen?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1176456/739431)

***Workaround:***

create a text file named `99-a11y-settings` in the direcotry `/usr/share/gdm/dconf/` with below command.

```
sudo touch /usr/share/gdm/dconf/99-a11y-settings
```

edit the file and put your key with values like below content

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gdm/dconf/99-a11y-settings
```

Content:

```
[org/gnome/desktop/a11y]
always-show-universal-access-status=false
```

then run

```
sudo dconf update
```

Reboot is required for the change to come in Action.

---

Here is my actual file content:

```
[org/gnome/desktop/a11y]
always-show-universal-access-status=false

[org/gnome/desktop/interface]
clock-show-seconds=true
clock-show-date=true
cursor-theme='DMZ-White'
cursor-size=48

[org/gnome/login-screen]
banner-message-enable=true
banner-message-text='TESTING WELCOME MESSAGE'

[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/color]
night-light-enabled=true
```

[image]

---

Why the file is kept in `/usr/share/gdm/dconf/` directory? Because the file `/usr/share/gdm/dconf/00-upstream-settings` says (some of the content only)

```
# This file is part of the GDM packaging and should not be changed.
#
# Instead create your own file next to it with a higher numbered prefix,
# and run
#
#       dconf update
#
```

and the file `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-default` is connected with `/usr/share/gdm/dconf/90-debian-settings` as a symbolic link and not working.

Thus as a workaround higher number 99 is taken as oppose to 90, 91 may also work.

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks, finally worked :)
'''